# How Come My Value Keeps Outputting 1.0? - General Polynomial Evaluator

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently working on a program for my lab class and I am needing help with the output. 
The prompt is to write a general code that evaluates a polynomial (ex: 5x^4+3x^3+2x^2). The instructions say that I have to use an array of coefficients in which the size of the array is the inputted degree "n". The user then has to input a value of x then solve the value for each individual polynomial and add it all together.

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GenPol {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    String AnsPol = "yes";
    while(AnsPol.equals("yes")) {
        System.out.println("Please enter the largest degree of polynomial");
        int n = in.nextInt();

        if((n>0 || n==0)) {
           double[] x = new double[n+1];
           int arrayLength = x.length;
           for(int degreeLength=0; degreeLength<=arrayLength; degreeLength++){
                double totalVal=0; //overall accumulator
                double indiV =0; //individual accumulator
                for(int i=0; i<=arrayLength; arrayLength--) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter the coefficient for 
                degree " + arrayLength + ":");
                    double coefficient = in.nextDouble();
                    indiV=coefficient;
                }

                System.out.println("Please enter the value for x: ");
                double xVal = in.nextDouble();

                double xPowered = Math.pow(xVal, degreeLength);
                double indivVal = indiV*xPowered;
                x[degreeLength] = indivVal; //store this value into this 
                element
                totalVal += x[degreeLength]; //add the elements together

                String XAns = "yes";
                while(XAns.equals("yes")) {
                    System.out.println("The total value is " + totalVal);

                    System.out.println("Would you like to evaluate another 
                    value of x?");
                    XAns = in.nextLine();
                }

            }
        } else{
            System.out.println("Please enter a degree that's greater than or 
        equal to 0.");
           }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output when I did a test run:

```
Please enter the largest degree of polynomial
3
Please enter the coefficient for degree 4:
3
Please enter the coefficient for degree 3:
1
Please enter the coefficient for degree 2:
2
Please enter the coefficient for degree 1:
2
Please enter the coefficient for degree 0:
1
Please enter the value for x: 
2
The total value is 1.0
Would you like to evaluate another value of x?
Please enter the largest degree of polynomial
```

Can someone point me to the right direction in terms of my iteration? I'm not entirely sure why my total value keeps outputting 1.0. And also if my loops are properly placed?
Thank you so much!!

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is no evidence of any debugging performed on this code.  Please [edit] your question to show us what your debugging has uncovered, as well as a specific question about a specific line of code.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Can you edit your question, describe in short what a polynomial is, what your code is supposed to do, provide sample input and output of how a working code should behave.

Comment: Please also rename your variables with sensible names... names like n (largestPolynomialDegree might be a better name) and x are just confusing.

Comment: Also, I think if you stepped through this with the debugger you will find your mistake quite quickly... If you don't know how to use the debugger, learn... it's well worth the effort.

Answer (score 1):

First to make things easier for you i'd recommend creating one loop in  the main method. have it call getInput(), calc(), displayResults() and do those jobs in those methods. Second what is going on here `(n>0 || n==0)`? use n>=0 . third... your main problem lies here

```
for(int i=0; i<=arrayLength; arrayLength--) {
    System.out.println("Please enter the coefficient for 
    degree " + arrayLength + ":");
    double coefficient = in.nextDouble();
    indiV=coefficient;
}
```

if you're still unable to figure it out post and get more hints.

Comment: Not sure if I should upvote because this is indeed correct, or downvote for failing to actually answer the question....

Comment: well no one is going to come to this answer because of something wrong in their code. so we're trying to help this one guy. the above comments seem to be trying to get the OP to do some work on their own. I'm providing some assistance to see if he can get there on his own, which is more helpful to him than just giving him the answer. vote your conscious

Comment: Good point... Although I still hope people will see this thread, see the answer here and then analyse their own problems to see if the same this is being done.